# can i add backend_user image to tx_news?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'm using tx_news extension 6.3 and Typo3 7.6.

I read in documentation this :

Author name & email
By using the following code in the PageTsConig, the fields Author and Author Email are prefilled with the name and email address of the current backend user

tx_news.predefine.author  = 1

My question is : I like to add the backend_user profile image to every news article that he make, mean not only his name and his email. is that possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can take use this extension [TYPO3 CMS Extension news_feuser](https://github.com/georgringer/news_feuser)

Comment: Please don't only link but add some more information like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks, but this is using the fe_user, and i like to add the be_user image.

Comment: :) I know but You can change fe_user on the the be_user,,, this ext: news_feuser like example